# Does intern JS have a mocha test runner

Tags: javascript, user-interface, automated-tests, intern, ui-testing

I want to write my tests using the mocha framework i.e

```
  describe('',function(){
      it('', function()){
      });
   });
```

Can this be done for my intern tests, does intern have a mocha test runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a mocha-like interface rather than necessarily using mocha itself. If that's the case, Intern offers the `bdd` interface. You could do something like:

```
var bdd = require('intern!bdd');
var describe = bdd.describe;
var it = bdd.it;

describe('', function(){
    it('', function(){
    });
});
```